# Linear Systems Word application

Tags: linear-algebra

Bob leaves Jim's house at 9 am driving at 90 km/hr. At 10 am Jim realises Bob left his wallet and heads out at 110 km per hour. Assuming they take the same route, what time will they meet?

Comment: To solve these kinds of questions it's best to set a few variables (eg. let $s_B$ be Bob's speed) and form equations you can solve. All you need to know is that $\text{Speed}=\frac{\text{Distance}}{\text{time}}$

Comment: @Shuri2060 given distance traveled in that original time ( I know it), it can reduced a couple differences and an add.

Comment: okay a multiply, a subtract, a division, and an add actually.

Answer (score 0):

Let set $t=0$ (in hour) for the moment Bob leave Jim's house.

Assuming he didn't burn from the instant acceleration from 0 to 90km/h, we have $d_{Bob}$ the distance bob travelled :

$$d_{Bob} = 90\cdot t$$

One hour later, at $t=1$, Jim leaves. So we got :

$$d_{Jim} = 110 \cdot (t-1) $$

Now since it is said that they left at the same point and took the same route, they will meet when $d_{Bob} = d_{Jim}$. Which is to say we have to solve for $t$:

$$90\cdot t = 110 \cdot (t-1)$$

Which gives $$t=5.5\text{ Hours or }t= 5\text{ Hours }30 \text{ Minutes }$$

Comment: to clarify this answer this t is from the time bob left not from when jim left.

Comment: *"Let set $t=0$ (in hour) for the moment Bob leave Jim's house."* I think this is pretty explicit ?

Comment: okay I guess I was just idiot proofing.  as you can do it from the time jim left as well.

Comment: Oh but yes indeed there's a lot of ways to do this, that's why you have specify when $t=0$ is. Sorry if I sounded rude mate.